# Why a Method in nested loops is called only on iteration of the first one!

Tags: c#, .net

*Would anybody explain me, please, why is the method executed only on iterations of the first loop and the second one modify only the end2 variable but the method isn't called!!!
I hope my explanation of the problem is clear enough.*

**OK I found something through debugging! The problem isn't as I describe it, the loops work correct and the method wrong!
Thank you for your advices I appreciate your help**

```
int[] array = {7,3,5,4,9,1,3,2,5};    
for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i *= 2)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < array.Length - i; j += 2*i)
    {
        end2 = (2 * j < array.Length - i) ? (2 * i) : (array.Length - j);
        Method(j, i, end2, array);
    }
}
```

Thank you
BR

Stephan

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger paying attention to i, j, and array.Length.  We don't know what array.Length is in your code, so we can't trace it for you.

Comment: for your testing what is the length of your array?  I want to work out how many loops it should be doing.  I don't see anything that would prevent your method from being called.  Also please just for my own sanity create two more variables in your code one would be set to (array.Length) before your first loop and the other would be set to  (firstNewVariableCreated - i).  Your code will execute faster and be more readable by doing this.

Comment: I've added the array and I'll try your advice

Comment: Does Method() alter the contents of array[]?  The unusual behavior could be explained if array.Length isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Yes it sorts it using MergeSort, however I can't check my method if it works correctly when sometimes it's not executed in some of the iterations of the loops!

Comment: How are you determining that Method() is only called once?  Does Method() do anything to the array passed in, for instance, clear it?

Comment: You need to show us `Method` because if I replace that call with `Console.WriteLine(end2);` I get 2
2
5
3
4
5
8
16

Comment: Also it does not look like any implementation of MergeSort I've seen and I struggled with MergeSort recently http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2011/01/01/lazy-evaluation-is-no-friend-of-mutable-state

Comment: I found something through debugging! The problem isn't as I describe it, the loops work correct and the method wrong! Thank you for your advices I appreciate your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you use nested loops, then in your case the outer loop is executed once with i = 1. This means the inner loop is executed with j= 0 until j receives the limit j < array.Length - 1.

Then the outer loop again is executed with i = 2. That means the inner loop is sexecuted with j = 0 until j receives the limit j < array.Length - 2;

This continues until the outer loop reaches its limit.

Comment: Yes that's correct but the problem is that the Method is executed on j=0 only

Comment: then why would need to now array.Length